# Can I sign iOS apps on Linux? (Using maybe a port of codesign?)

Tags: ios, linux, debian, codesign

I'd like to sign my iOS apps on a Linux box (Debian 5 if it matters). Does anyone know if this is possible? (Let's not get into *why* I'd want to do this since it's specific to my environment.)

I see source code to codesign on Apple's site but before I get into the weeds pulling it over and trying to build it myself, I wondered if anyone knows of an existing port.

I'd heard that codesign is not really OSX-specific and may exist on other OS's but there's always a chance Apple has tweaked it to their own needs. I wonder if an app signed by something other than Apple's codesign will run on an iOS device.

If it matters, the signed apps are meant for enterprise users and will not go in the iTunes App Store.

Comment: Flash CS5 does that on Windows and Mac.

Comment: I spent a chunk of time downloading Apple's sources and trying to get them to build but still no solution. Codesign for OSX has heavily deviated from the original and is now intertwined with Apple's frameworks. While Apple is true to the letter of the open-source license and supplies their modified source, they are not obligated to supply a working, cross-platform build system so they don't.

Answer (score 2):

Saurik wrote a codesigning utility called ldid, I think for OS X and iOS. It also might be available for Linux though.

Comment: I looked at ldid. Unfortunately, ldid is not being maintained, hasn't been updated in several years, and the code is tough to maintain/update since the code memory maps the target file and is laden with macros to handle endian issues.

Comment: Details and source for ldid can be found at http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Ldid.

Answer (score -1):

Check out [JTool](http://newosxbook.com/tools/jtool.html).

[Code signing](http://newosxbook.com/tools/jtool.html#codesign) is considered to be the second most useful feature of JTool. With iOS security revolving around code signatures and entitlements, it's important to have a way to quickly determine what given entitlements a binary possesses and how it is signed. OS X has [`codesign(1)`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html), but I find it crude (at best) - and what more there's no port to iOS, where it's really necessary.